# python ldap3 bulk delete users and groups

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap3

Is there any way to delete from AD pack of objects with python ldap3?
Something like

```
conn.delete("(CN='auto*'),CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=com")
```

doesn't find any

TIA!

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The LDAP protocol doesn't allow such an operation. You must use a conn.delete() for each user to delete.

Comment: I also had to use `delete_s` for deleting multiple objects from LDAP in a `for` loop.